# Updating Nginx from 1.3.0 to 1.4.1 while using Plesk 11

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, nginx, plesk

Is it possible to upgrade the nginx version witch was originally installed with plesk to the newest stable version without bricking the whole web-server?

I got the nginx repository and tried to apt-get upgrade it, but it didn't upgrade the nginx version.
So i tried "apt-get -s install nginx" and it showed 3 packages to install, it seems the "plesk-nginx" was modified in some way. Did someone install a new nginx version on a plesk environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to upgrade packages provided by Plesk with other packages. They will either conflict with each other or your package management won't allow you to install them at all because of package conflicts.

Additionally, Plesk packages are usually heavily patched according to Plesk's needs, so even if you should manage to install another nginx, Plesk will probably not be able to work with it. You will have to wait until the Plesk-package gets updated.